# Building a matrix from the columns of others

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, column

A is a `n x m` matrix, B is a matrix `p x m`, I wish to build C from appending the ith column of A and ith column of B, for all i from 1 to m so that C is a `(n+p) x m` matrix. How do I do that?
All of n,m, p are parameters that may vary.
Thanks!

Comment: BTW, 'Table[Join[c[[All, i]], cbar[[All, j]]], {j, 1, T}]' does not work.

Answer (score 7):

```
n = 4; p = 2; m = 3;

aa = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {n, m}];

bb = Array[Subscript[b, ##] &, {p, m}];
```

### [`Join`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html)

```
cc = Join[aa, bb];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ aa
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\
 a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} \\
 a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ bb
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & b_{1,3} \\
 b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & b_{2,3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ cc
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\
 a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} \\
 a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} \\
 b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & b_{1,3} \\
 b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & b_{2,3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

### [`ArrayReshape`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html)

```
cc2 = ArrayReshape[{aa, bb}, {n + p, m}]

cc2 == cc
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

### [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)

```
cc3 = Flatten[{aa, bb}, 1]

cc3 == cc
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: @klgr `PadRight[aa,n+p,bb]` fails when `n=4;p=3;m=2; ` for example?

Comment: Thank you @creidhne. Removed `PadRight`.

Answer (score 5):

> appending the ith column of A and ith column of B

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

[image]

```
B = {{10, 11, 12}, {14, 15, 16}};
```

[image]

```
ArrayFlatten[{{A}, {B}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes does work, however, I just saw that I had a mistake in my formula which I said did not work. It should read 'Table[Join[c[[All, j]], cbar[[All, j]]], {j, 1, T}]'

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works